# 2倍サイズに書き出した画像が通常ディスプレイでぼやけてしまう

Tags: html, css, png

Retinaディスプレイ対応のため、画像、動画を2倍で書き出したのですが、Retinaディスプレイは綺麗に表示されますが、通常ディスプレイではぼやけてしまいます。
何か対応はありますか？

Comment: 画像の解像度が２倍になっているものを圧縮させて表示させているのであれば通常ディスプレイでぼやけるとは考えにくいです。お手数ですがサンプルの画像（画像のサイズと解像度も併せて）とどのようにHTMLに記述しているかソースコードもご提示ください。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Chrome で起こるのであれば画像サイズがちょうど2倍になっていなければぼやけることがあります。

```
img {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

を適用することで解消されるかもしれません。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
画像の問題上記追加で解消されました。